# Devel::Peek output results in STDERR

Tags: perl, stderr

I'm trying to work out why my debugging from **Devel::Peek::Dump** isn't showing in my log file. I'm just doing this to pass the *STDERR* output:

```
open (STDERR, ">>/home/chambres/web/foo.org/public_html/cgi-bin/links/admin/stripe-booking.log") || die $!;
```

...and then this in my script:

```
use Devel::Peek;
print STDERR "name AFTER encoded: \n";
Dump($add_common->{name});
```

All I get in the log file is:

> name AFTER encoded:

I know `$add_common->{name}` has a value, so I'm a bit confused as to why its not showing up. I'm trying to see some debug output from someone running a live script.

Comment: Can't reproduce.  Btw -- the shown code has "_... before ..._" but the shown output has "_... AFTER ..._" -- a mistake in posting? Or not? Can you post a complete (short) program that demos this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dump` writes to fd 2. `STDERR` originally wraps fd 2, so something must have changed STDERR to get the behaviour you observe.

As you can see, redirecting STDERR works fine when STDERR is associated with fd 2:

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e'
   use Devel::Peek qw( Dump );
   open STDERR, ">>", "a" or die $!;
   say fileno(STDERR);
   Dump(undef);
'
2

$ cat a
SV = NULL(0x0) at 0x55d63aab13b0
  REFCNT = 2147483637
  FLAGS = (READONLY,PROTECT)
```

No so much when STDERR is associated with fd 3:

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e'
   use Devel::Peek qw( Dump );
   local *STDERR;
   open STDERR, ">>", "b" or die $!;
   say fileno(STDERR);
   Dump(undef);
'
3
SV = NULL(0x0) at 0x56050b00b3b0
  REFCNT = 2147483637
  FLAGS = (READONLY,PROTECT)

$ cat b
```

You could create a handle for fd 2, and redirect it.

```
$ perl -M5.010 -e'
   use Devel::Peek qw( Dump );
   open(my $fd2, ">&=", 2) or die $!;
   say fileno($fd2);
   open $fd2, ">>", "c" or die $!;
   say fileno($fd2);
   Dump(undef);
'
2
2

$ cat c
SV = NULL(0x0) at 0x5582af5dc3b0
  REFCNT = 2147483637
  FLAGS = (READONLY,PROTECT)
```

---

Since that changes the fd 2 of the process, the above workaround would affect Apache in its entirety in a mod_perl setting.

It sounds like you're primarily interested in the internal storage format used by a string. If so, you can get it using

```perl
utf8::is_utf8($s)
```

It returns true if the string is using the "upgraded" storage format (the `SVf_UTF8` flag is set).

It returns true if the string is using the "downgraded" storage format (the `SVf_UTF8` flag is clear). Presumably, it also returns false if the scalar doesn't contain a string.

But you're almost garanteed to be doing something wrong. If you're trying to work around a bug in an XS module, all you need is `utf8::upgrade` and/or `utf8::downgrade`.

Comment: thanks - that went right over my head =) I think you are right though, something has messed with the output of STDERR. If I remove my custom STDERR filehander (going to my custom file), and then have:  `print STDERR "FOO\n"; use Devel::Peek; Dump("foo");` ... then nothing is printed to STDERR in the normal Apache log file. I'll do some digging . Thanks!

Comment: OMG I feel like such an idiot... it WAS working, but I hadn't restarted mod_perl!!!!! Now I restarted mod_perl, and it works as expected. One of those "I should have had another cup of coffee" kind of days today I think! ;)

Comment: hmm it still doesn't work. It seemed to, and now its not showing in the log again. Literally all I want to do, is dump the values of a string (to check for utf8 flags, character codes etc). Is there a module that will do that, and just store it to a variable so I can dump it myself?

Comment: Added to answer.

Comment: How would i instead write Dump to a variable? This is not working for me: `open $fd2, ">>", \$var`

Comment: It appears that when using `Dump`, flush does NOT occur until the file handle is closed.